# Тест на правильность содержимого поля title

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha

Разбираюсь с тестированием. Нужно написать тест для проверки на то, что в нужном мне запросе есть title с нужным содержимым.
 Вот запрос: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 .
 Как мне проверить что в его *title* лежит следующий контент: *"sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"*?
**Важно:** использовать для теста нужно **mocha, superAgent**.
Или подскажите как загуглить чтобы найти ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация с примерами](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/docs/test.html). Нам нужно сравнить два значения, используем should.equal;

объявляем ожидаемое значение переменной (тайтла), совершаем запрос, обращаемся к свойству объекта, полученного в виде json-ответа на запрос, сравниваем значение свойства объекта со значением переменной, отлавливая случай несовпадения значений:

```
done => {
      const titleExpectedValue = "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit";
      request
      .get(`${uri}/${endpoint}`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        try {
        res.title.should.equal(titleExpectedValue);
        done();
        } catch(e) { done(e); }
      });
    }
```